# Dynamic user permission to secure folders in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Using MVC3 I am trying to come up with method of checking the database to see if a user is allowed access to a folder. The administrator has individual control over each user's permission to courses, so I cannot control this from web.config.

The screenshot below provides an example of what I am trying to accomplish: *courseA* is an example of one of many folders that only certain users will be allowed access to. My thinking is that I could use a CourseController action like `OpenCourse(int id)` to check against the db if a user has access to a course, and if so then "allow access" to the entire course folder and open the *player.html* file contained within it. The user's permission to each file within *courseA* folder would probably need to persist for the user's session.

[image]

Is it even possible to do something like this from within the MVC View folder, or should the *courseA* folder sit somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this sort of restriction in your database calls. You could say for example:

```
var courses =  ListCoursesForUser(userId);
```

Then when accessing a specific course you can reuse this:

```
public doSomethingWithCourse(courseId, userId)
{
   var courses =  ListCoursesForUser(userId);

   if(courses.Any(c => c.courseId == courseId))
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I was however looking for a solution on the MVC 3 side of things.. In my controller I override 'OnActionExecuting' and within that I do something similar to what you suggested. Still looking for a more elegant solution than 'OnActionExecuting'

Comment: You should also be able to do this in the model with similar code